# adding into the file name for subfolders with batch

Tags: file, batch-file, rename, filenames

So with some effort i managed to mine this gem from the stack overflow:

```
rem @echo off
setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in ("C:\users\*.txt") do (
    copy "%%a" "%%~dpna.ab%%~xa"
    del "%%a" 
)
endlocal
```

It works beautifully so long as the files specified aren't in a subfolder within the given path. It seems I cannot fix the issue to envelope subfolders as well.

Is there a way to adjust this code to change the filename by extension given for subfolders as well?

Comment: Are you saying you want to recurse into sub folders? The `FOR` command has an `/R` option to do that.  You can read about it by opening up a command prompt and typing: `FOR /?` to read the help and usage.

Comment: What i need the code to do is to find all .txt files and ad .ab into the file name wether they are located inside the C:\users\ or its subfolders.

Comment: Then you want to use the `/R` option as I stated in my previous comment.

Comment: Why do you copy and delete files when renaming was enough?

Comment: Have you thought about checking to make sure the file hasn't been renamed yet before renaming it again?

Comment: `for /R "C:\users" %%A in (*.txt) do REN "%%A" "%%~nA.ab%%~xA"`
Note that the second parameter of `ren` should be a _file_, not a _path_. There's no need for delayed expansion also.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped. I have gone over the RENAME properties of the function withing command prompt and its working beautifully. Squashman did point out that checking names before renaming them so duplicate or extended appends of the .ab within the name dont happen. Any ideas how to solve that wrinkle? I have been thinking of using IF command, any other better ideas?

Comment: @Squashman I tried doing this:

`rem @echo off

FOR /R "%pathname%" %%G in (*.txt) DO (
     IF "%%G" == "%%~nG.ab.txt" (
        SKIP
      ) ELSE (
        REN "%%G" "%%~nG.ab.txt"
      )
)

pause`
However it doesn't work, most likely cause i am using the IF parenthesis in the wrong way?